# R pass a vector in crossing function

Tags: r, tidyr

I'm trying to pass a vector in the tidyr 'crossing' function, but I don't see how to do it. Here's what I want to do: I want to crossproduct the objects **michel**, **anita**, **robert** to obtain the dataframe **everybody** as follow:

```
# objects to combine

michel <- c("Berlin","Tokyo","Amsterdam")
anita <- c("London","Montreal")
robert <- "Moscow"

# combination

library(tidyr)

everybody <- crossing(michel,anita,robert)
```

Thing is, I want to pick the list **michel, anita, robert**  from a dataframe (or vector), then pass that vector to the crossing function (so that **everybody2** is the same as **everybody**):

```
# vector with names:

vector1 <- as.data.frame(c("michel","anita","robert"))

# how to pass 'vector1' into crossing?

everybody2 <- crossing(vector1)
```

I don't see how I can make it work... any advice?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `mget` to return the values of the string objects

```
everybody2 <- crossing(!!! mget(vector1[[1]]))
identical(everybody, everybody2)
#[1] TRUE
```

Or another option is `do.call`

```
do.call(crossing, mget(vector1[[1]]))
```

Here, the 'vector1' is a `data.frame` with single column of strings.  We extract the first column with `[[1]]`, get the value of string objects with `mget` into a `list`, splice the list (`!!!`) in `crossing`

NOTE: We used `R 4.0` and the default option in `data.frame` or `as.data.frame` is `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`.  If the R version is  < 4.0, then convert the `factor` class to `character` with `as.character` or specify `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in `as.data.frame`

```
crossing(!!! mget(as.character(vector1[[1]])))
```

---

Or using `base R` with `expand.grid`

```
expand.grid(mget(vector1[[1]]))
```